# Passing data between functions swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I know this might possibly be a really stupid question and something i might have missed in programming class, but im trying to pass data between two functions and any way i do it the error pops up of data not existing.

[image]

Comment: Rule #1: Post *code,* not screenshots.

Comment: Declare tags variable globally

Comment: You can use `tags` if the `deleteHandler` is declared inline (rather than as separate function).

Answer (score 1):

While using an instance variable is a solution, it's also possible to keep the functions pure:

```
func deleteHandler(tags: String) { // not sure what the correct type is
   ...
}
```

Note that you don't need to pass the action. To use the function, you can wrap it into a closure:

```
let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default) { _ in
   self.deleteHandler(tags)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ‘keep the function pure’?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the local variable out side the method.
Your `tags` is local variable in `didselect` method

please declare as global the assign the value in `didselect` method and use it out side the `function`

It may helps to you Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Declare tags globally by including this outside the function:

```
var tags = String()
```

Then assign the value by including this inside the didSelect function:

```
tags = posts2[indexPath.row].photoUrl
```

This is assuming the photoUrl is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use completion handler of Delete action inside didSelectrow.

```
let deleteaction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { _ in
       self.deleteHandler(tags: "https://")// Here pass your parameter
 })
alertController.addAction(deleteaction)


func deleteHandler(tags: String) {
        // delete handler code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tag = indexPath.row
    let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Some Alert", message: "You sure you want to delete this?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (success) in
        self.deleteHandler(tag: tag)
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And write your selector like:

```
    @objc func deleteHandler(tag: Int) -> Void{
    //delete element at tag
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could sort of export the value you want to use by adding it to UserDefaults then call it back into the next space where you need it. Just remember to sync the point where the original value is created so it is always upto date, else you could find yourself with extra rows and no data or worse Old data.

I suppose it is quite a bulky way to do it but it is a solution.